# Term for certain periods of time

Tags: word-choice

I'm trying to find the words for an essay to describe some time frames. I have a time frame of "Last 7 days" which is pretty self explanatory.

However, I'm trying to find the best wording to describe the same period but two weeks ago, three weeks ago and four weeks ago. Can't use "Last 14 days" for example as that wouldn't be accurate.

Is there any term I could be using here?

Comment: You could use *"the last seven days"* and *"the previous seven days"*. If you want to go back any farther, I think you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is a specific term to refer to the periods of time you are describing:

To avoid misunderstanding or unusual expressions I suggest you say:

> - During the week from...to.. (showing the specific dates you are referring to)

- In the week from the 4th to the 11th of January I stayed in NYC.

Comment: How is 'the last fortnight' any improvement on 'the last 14 days'? OP wants to include just days -14 to -8, not -14 to -1.

Comment: You mean..the first week of the last fortnight!!

Answer (score 0):

Every week from (date) till (date) . or if you are counting upto today or previous day every week from (date) till ( today/yesterday)

Answer (score 0):

To denote a period of two weeks, there is a term called 'fortnight'.
If you say "In the first fortnight of April..." you mean to say that "In the first two weeks of April..."
Example: We can arrange the meeting in the end of the second fortnight of this month.